# Python string formatting with percent sign

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am trying to do exactly the following:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> y = 'hello'
>>> '%d,%d,%s' % (x[0], x[1], y)
'1,2,hello'
```

However, I have a long `x`, more than two items, so I tried:

```
>>> '%d,%d,%s' % (*x, y)
```

but it is syntax error. What would be the proper way of doing this without indexing like the first example?

Comment: The Pythonic way would be to use `str.format`.

Comment: it's arguable whether it's more "pythonic" but `str.format` would allow you to use `*args` expansion since it's a method call

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`str % ..` accepts a *tuple* as a right-hand operand, so you can do the following:

```
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> y = 'hello'
>>> '%d,%d,%s' % (x + (y,))  # Building a tuple of `(1, 2, 'hello')`
'1,2,hello'
```

Your try should work in **Python 3**, where [`Additional Unpacking Generalizations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) is supported, but not in Python 2.x:

```
>>> '%d,%d,%s' % (*x, y)
'1,2,hello'
```

Comment: Actuall the extended iterable unpacking does **not** allow that syntax (python3.4): `>>> '%d,%d,%s' % (*x, y)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
`  Maybe it'll be allowed by python3.5's [Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Comment: @Bakuriu, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps have a look at [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
>>> x = (5,7)
>>> template = 'first: {}, second: {}'
>>> template.format(*x)
'first: 5, second: 7'
```

### Update:

For completeness I am also including *additional unpacking generalizations* described by [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). The extended syntax was introduced in **Python 3.5**, and the following is no longer a syntax error:

```
>>> x = (5, 7)
>>> y = 42
>>> template = 'first: {}, second: {}, last: {}'
>>> template.format(*x, y)  # valid in Python3.5+
'first: 5, second: 7, last: 42'
```

In **Python 3.4 and below**, however, if you want to pass additional arguments after the unpacked tuple, you are probably best off to pass them as *named arguments*:

```
>>> x = (5, 7)
>>> y = 42
>>> template = 'first: {}, second: {}, last: {last}'
>>> template.format(*x, last=y)
'first: 5, second: 7, last: 42'
```

This avoids the need to build a new tuple containing one extra element at  the end.

Comment: This belongs in a comment, not as an answer, unless you expand on it and show how to use `str.format()` to do what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, was writing that but posted an answer by accident too fast.

Comment: How to adopt this to my previous example? `'{},{},{}'.format( *x,y )` still does not work?

Comment: `'{1},{2},{0}'.format(y, *x )` - positional arguments expansion operator must come after all other positional arguments - but you can use a trick and mark the placeholders in the template to change the order.

Comment: @plamut Note that [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) changes that and allows `.format(*x, y)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, I know, but it's only going to be introduced in Python 3.5 (OP uses a different version). Thanks for mentioning it nevertheless!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `str.format` instead `str %` since its is "more modern" and also has a better set of features. That said what you want is:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> y = 'hello'
>>> '{},{},{}'.format(*(x + (y,)))
1,2,hello
```

For all cool features of `format` (and some related to `%` as well) take a look at [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/).